# Difference between these two functions

Tags: javascript, function

While reading "Javascript the Good Parts", came across this bit of code in the "module" chapter.

```
var serial_maker = function (  ) {

            // Produce an object that produces unique strings. A
            // unique string is made up of two parts: a prefix
            // and a sequence number. The object comes with
            // methods for setting the prefix and sequence
            // number, and a gensym method that produces unique
            // strings.

                var prefix = '';
                var seq = 0;

                return {
                    set_prefix: function (p) {
                        prefix = String(p);
                    },
                    set_seq: function (s) {
                        seq = s;
                    },
                    gensym: function ( ) {
                        var result = prefix + seq;
                        console.log(result);

                        seq += 1;
                        return result;
                    }
                };
            };
var seqer = serial_maker( );
seqer.set_prefix('Q');
seqer.set_seq(1000);
var unique = seqer.gensym( ); // unique is "Q1000
```

My question is: whats the difference between the above and this bit here:

```
var other_serial_maker = function(pre, num){

        return pre + num;

    };

    var makeSerial = other_serial_maker("Q", 1000);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only objective to to generate the string `Q1000` then no difference, but that's not the point. The example from the book is using a closure so that the `prefix` and `seq` parts are private and only accessible from within the function.

So the idea is, you can do this:

```
 var unique = seqer.gensym( ); // unique is "Q1000"
```

And then you can do this

```
 var anotherUnique = seqer.gensym( ); // unique is "Q1001"
```

Because the `serial_maker` keeps track of it's own state, which your code does not. If we use the code from the book, then after setting up the `serial_maker` we could call `.gensym` as many times as we wanted and get a different result. With your code, you'd need to somehow keep track of which codes you've used already.

Comment: Thanks for this clear explanation. Still trying to wrap my head aroudn closures...

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is that the outer `function` scope contains a declaration of `prefix` and `seq`, so they are contained in a closure that will follow the `seqer` object around.

In other words, the example from the book returns an object with a state whereas your example is a plain function (that doesn't use any state).

Answer (score 0):

The point of serial_maker is that it stores state in seq for each serial maker that ensures any one won't produce duplicates.  Provided the prefixes are distinct, there won't be duplicates across the serial makers either.

Comment: So long as you only call `.set_seq` once!

Comment: True - if it had been me, I would have made the initial values parameters and not allowed updates after that.

Comment: Me too, seems like a much better solution.